# How do I solve $y+x\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}=3\; $ given $(x=1,y=1) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$y+x\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}=3\; (x=1,y=1)$

Any help would be much appreciated.

$$x\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}=3-y$$

$$\int \frac{1}{3-y} dy=\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$

$$3-y=x\cdot (\pm e^{C})$$

$$y=-x+3\cdot (\pm e^{C})$$

Let $(\pm e^{C}) = k$

$y=k(-x+3)$, so $ k=\frac{1}{2} from (1,1)$

$y=-\frac{1}{2}(x-3)$

Is this right?? I have no idea.

Comment: This is a separable equation. Can you separate it?

Comment: What have you tried yet ? Please show us your work and we might point where you are going wrong.

Comment: Please also see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) if you haven't seen it already. In future, we expect you to show more effort and give the context to your question since you are not a new user.

Comment: just typing my working out. a sec

Comment: write it $(xy)'=3$ And integrate.

Comment: Your third step in the resolution is wrong. Double check the integrals.

Comment: yep realised its wrong thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y+xy'=(xy)'$$ and a solution is

$$xy=3x+c,$$ with
$$1\cdot1=3\cdot1+c.$$

---

Alternatively, with $z:=xy$, we have pure differentials

$$dz=3\,dx$$ which integrate from $(1,1)$ to $(x,z)$ as $$z-1=xy-1=3x-3.$$

---

Yet alternatively:

The homogeneous equation is

$$y+xy'=0$$ or $$\frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dy}y=0$$

or

$$\log(xy)=c.$$

Now *by inspection* of the non-homogeneous equation, $$y=3$$ is a particular solution, and the general solution is

$$y=3+\frac cx.$$

Answer (score 5):

It is a linear ODE:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x}=\frac{3}{x}$$
The integrating factor $I=e^{\int 1/x ~dx}=x$
So $$y=\frac{1}{x} \int 3 dx+\frac{c}{x} \implies y=3+\frac{c}{x}$$
$y(1)=1$ gives $c=-2$.
So $$y=3-\frac{2}{x}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: This is **variable separable**.

$$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{3-y}=\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{x}, \ y(1)=1$$

Can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You made a little mistake here :
$$\int \frac{1}{3-y} dy=\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$
You should rewrite it as:
$$-\int \frac{1}{y-3} dy=\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$
Then write it the way you did:
$$(y-3)^{-1}=kx$$
And here
$$3-y=x\cdot (\pm e^{C})$$
This should yields:
$$\implies y=3-kx$$
And not:
$$y=k(3-x)$$